Need to get a schema definition in runtime
I want to get the Python schema definition for the table passed to the get_schema method in runtime.
class Test:
def __init__(self):
    self.schema_table1 = {
        "name": "str",
        "add": "str"
    }
    self.schema_table2 = {
        "n1": "str",
        "n2": "str"
    }

def get_schema(self, table_name):
    schema = table_name
    return schema

class Test2:
def __init__(self):
        self.test_obj = Test()

    def process(self):
        table_name = "schema_"+'table1'
        print(self.test_obj.get_schema(table_name))


test2_obj = Test2()
test2_obj.process()

Actual output:
schema_table1

Expected output:
{
     "name": "str",
      "add": "str"
}


Just store the schemas in a dictionary.

If you want to return variables with arbitrary names in a class, you can use getattr() to either return the variable, or return None.
Docs:

getattr(object, name, default)

Return the value of the named attribute
of object. name must be a string. If the string is the name of one of
the object’s attributes, the result is the value of that attribute.
For example, getattr(x, 'foobar') is equivalent to x.foobar


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.schema_table1 = {
            "name": "str",
            "add": "str"
        }
        self.schema_table2 = {
            "n1": "str",
            "n2": "str"
        }

    def get_schema(self, table_name):
        schema = getattr(self, table_name, None)
        return schema

class Test2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test_obj = Test()

    def process(self):
        table_name = "schema_" + 'table1'
        print(self.test_obj.get_schema(table_name))

test2_obj = Test2()
test2_obj.process()

This will safely fetch the variable if it exists, else it will return nothing back.
